# Äquivalent zu "when things go south"

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

Gibt es im Deutschen ein Äquivalent zu dem Ausdruck "when things go south" (= "wenn die Situation schlechter wird"), das auch darauf aufbaut, dass "südlich" als "nach unten" im Sinne von "schlechter" verstanden werden kann?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In den meisten Kontexten ist "going south" vergleichsweise schnell. Ein Plan und ein Meeting können "go south", aber nicht den Berg runter oder in den Keller oder den Bach runter. Die vorgeschlagenen Varianten passen in den wenigsten Kontexten und daher ist meine Antwort:

Nein, es gibt keinen Ausdruck, der die Bedeutung und Verwendung trifft und gleichzeitig auf der Idee von "Süden, unten" aufbaut.

Comment: Also ist "going south" auch in Situationen angebracht, die nur "nicht optimal" gelaufen sind? Ich hatte es bisher immer nur in extremen Fällen erlebt. z.B. auf Workplace SE als "Communicate with emails. You'll want to have a paper trail when things go south and you are blamed". Hast du zufällig Beispiele für diese abgeschwächte Verwendung?

Comment: @Christopher... von "abgeschwächt" war doch garnicht die Rede. "things go south" ist oft ein "turn for the worse(possibly worst)". Es ist nicht so sehr ein "Verfallen über die Zeit", und das ist aber genau was "den Bach runtergehen" und die anderen Vorschläge hier sind.

Comment: ach so, sorry. hatte "schneller" als "wird schneller verwendet" gelesen.

Comment: ich warte mal noch ab, ob Kommodore dazu noch etwas schreibt, sonst ändere ich die akzeptierte Antwort, deine klingt logisch

Comment: @Christopher... naja, die Frage ist halt, ob du nur ein Äquivalent suchst, das auf der gleichen Idee aufbaut, oder ob du was suchst, dass auch dasselbe bedeutet. Ich habe gedacht zweiteres, aber dann ist mir eingefallen, dass ja so konkret gar nicht nach Bedeutungsgleicheit gefragt war. Wie auch immer, mal sehen was die anderen sagen.

Comment: +1 weil ich die implizierte Geschwindigkeit von "going south" noch nicht kannte. "_steil_ bergab" und "in den Keller gehen" drücken für mich auch eine recht drastische Veränderung aus und enthalten zumindest das Bild einer nach unten gerichteten Bewegung, sind aber nicht so flexibel, was den Kontext betrifft. Mit "südlich" gibt es wohl wirklich nichts. Mir fällt in dem Zusammenhang auf, daß es bei uns auch kein Äquivalent zu [east|south|west|north]bound gibt. "Got on board on westbound 747" ist schon von der Idee her Englisch, oder?

Comment: "Going south" ist vergleichsweise schnell? Soll das ein Satz sein? `Ein Plan und ein Meeting können "go south",` - da stimmt die Grammatik nicht, so kann man weder reden, noch schreiben. Ich musste die Sätze mehrfach lesen um zu verstehen was Du sagen willst. Daher von mir ein Minus.

Comment: @userunknown... bisher haben es alle verstanden. Ich glaube, dass du es einfach nicht verstehen willst, weil es nicht "regelkonform" ist. Du kannst gerne eine andere Formulierung vorschlagen, und die Grammakik berichtigen wie es hier sonst auch Usus ist. Und ja, doch, so kann man super reden. Ich rede jeden Tag so, wenn ich über Englisch spreche und es funktioniert wunderbar. Ich kann es aber auch gerne Verdeutschen und sagen "south goen" wenn dir das lieber ist.

Comment: @Emanuel: Ich beschwerte micht nicht, dass man es nicht verstehen kann, sondern darüber, dass der sprachliche Ausdruck so miserabel ist, dass kaum verständlich ist. Dass man es mehrfach lesen muss, weil der Autor dachte, die Arbeit dem Leser aufzuhalsen. Dass Du jetzt alberne Vorschläge machst die erkennbar noch schlechter sind ist lustig, dass Du willst dass man Dir die Beiträge schreibt weniger - bei Dir weiß ich nämlich, dass Du ausdrücken könntest was Du meinst, wenn Du wolltest. Daher helfe ich nicht sondern vergebe ein Minus.

Comment: 'In den meisten Kontexten ist "es geht beragab" vergleichsweise schnell.' ist genauso falsch - das hat mit Englisch gar nichts zu tun.

Answer (score 10):

Mir fällt in diesem Zusammenhang jetzt nur

> … geht den Bach runter

ein. Hierbei wird zwar nicht "Süden" oder "südlich" verwendet, jedoch gibt es meines Wissens keine Redewendung dieser Art mit "Süden".

Comment: Vielen Dank! Schade, hätte das gerne ins deutsche übernommen, gefällt mir im englischen sehr gut.

Comment: Ich glaube ehrlich gesagt, dass "den Bach runtergehen" fast nie in Kontexten von "go south" verwenden kann. "go south" ist viel schneller und weniger fokussiert auf Qualitätsverminderung sondern auf "nichts funktioniert"

Answer (score 7):

[dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/english-german/to+go+south.html) hat eine ganze Liste von Übersetzungen von "to go south". Neben den bereits oben erwähnten Formulierungen "bergab gehen" und "den Bach runter gehen", bieten sich noch

> - auf dem absteigenden Ast sein
> - in den Keller gehen
> - in die Binsen gehen

an.

Answer (score 7):

Schneller als "den Bach runter" geht eine Situation wenn sie "kippt". 

Enthält allerdings auch keinen "Süden", nur ein implizites "nach unten".

Answer (score 6):

Ich kenne auch nichts mit "Süden" oder "südlich". Hab den [Redensarten-Index](http://www.redensarten-index.de) durchsucht und auch dort nichts gefunden. Ich wage zu behaupten, dass es nichts dergleichen gibt.

Ergänzend zu der [Antwort von Kommodore](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/17765/1224) sei noch

> bergab gehen

angeführt.

Comment: Ist meiner Ansicht nach auch viel zu langsam und wird in den meisten Kontexten nicht passen. -1

Answer (score 6):

deepl übersetzt es schön mit, wenn Dinge "aus dem Ruder laufen"

Answer (score 3):

Another option with a direct English equivalent:

> Wenn's schiefgeht

Meaning literally, "If it goes awry".

Answer (score -1):

Es gibt auch den schönen Ausdruck

> über die Wupper gehen

in diesem Zusammenhang.

Comment: Das bedeutet aber "sterben" oder "pleite gehen".

Comment: Auch, es kann aber auch bedeuten "kaputtgehen", z. B. bei einem Gerät.

Comment: Was synonym zu sterben ist, sofern ein Gerät denn "sterben" kann, aber mein Punkt ist, dass es nicht einen Abwärtstrend darstellen kann. Etwas, was über die Wupper geht, ist halt einfach quasi nicht mehr existent oder im Falle eines Unternehmens eventuell im Begriff seine Existenz zu verlieren. "go south" bedeutet aber nicht, dass etwas kaputt ist, seine Existenz verloren hat, oder gestorben ist.